# How to group a model data based on another model and paginate in django?

Tags: django, django-models, pagination, grouped-list

I have two models:

1. Category - Zero or multiple books can be in one category
2. Book - A book can have zero or one category

if I do `Book.objects.all()` I'll get something like `[book11, book10, book9, ...]` normally but I don't want that.
What I want is something like:

```
[
 [book11, book2, book1],
 [book10],
 [book8, book6],
 [book7],
 [book4, book3],
 ...
]
```

Where

- Books are grouped according to their category. The books that don't have a category will also include in the list as a single element group
- Ordering would be according to book's creation in reverse

For better understanding here is my model structure:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='books', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Do books have a field that contains their created datetime? Do you want this grouping in a template or as a Python object?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes books do have a field called created_at and want the grouping as Queryset of Book model

Comment: You can create a queryset that is ordered so that books with the same category are next to each other but you can't have a queryset that has sublists of results. Does my answer below help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

To do this grouping in Python code you can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby


qs = Book.objects.order_by('category', '-created_at')
grouped_books = groupby(qs, lambda book: book.category)
for category, books in grouped_books:
    print(category)
    print(list(books))
```

You can also do this in a template using the [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag

In your view pass this queryset to your template context

```
   books = Book.objects.order_by('category', '-created_at')
```

In your template

```
{% regroup books by category as category_list %}

<ul>
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li>{{ category.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for book in category.list %}
          <li>{{ book }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```